# Javascript POST request for Update, no HTML text update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been writting a CMS, and im currently working on a remote Updater script, so users can update the CMS with a click of a button. Problem is, i cant see to get this JS snippet below to work:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#update').html('Checking for updates...');
        check();
      });

    //function to check for new updates
    function check(){

        //use ajax to run the check
        $.post("http://updateserver.come/get_update.php", { version: cms_version },
            function(result){
                //if the result is 1
                if(result == 1){
                    //show that there are updates
                    $('#update').html('Updates is Available');
                }else{
                    //show that there are NO updates
                    $('#update').html('Updates are not Available');
                }
        });

    }
    </script>

<div id="update"></div>
```

The problem is, when JS gets the response, it doesnt update the text between the divs. Anyone have a clue why this is?

Comment: did you check the firebug for any errors

Comment: The problem is not that the `div` is not updated (since it is - I tested it just fine), I think. Have you verified that you DO receive a response?

Comment: what is cms_version here . put alert inside  function(result){
and check it working

Comment: this is what i get in the web console "[23:45:11.800] POST http://wilson212.net/test.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 167ms]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web applications are limited by the so-called [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which restricts requests to the same domain.  If your app doesn't live in the same domain as the web service you're trying to POST to, the browser won't let it happen.

Comment: do maybe i should use ajax and connect to a local script that will use file_get_contents('http://updateserver.com/updates.php?version=5'); ?

Comment: The technique you're describing is called using a proxy, and it's one of the most widely suggested ways of circumventing the Same Origin Proxy.  So yes, that's one way of doing it.  If you control the update server there are other options, but if you don't, then implementing a proxy is a fine solution.